# How can spouse transfer title to car in Oklahoma?

Tags: property, vehicle

Husband is in Jail and wife has possession of the car. It is in his name. How can title be transferred from him to her in Oklahoma?

However, we don't have the title. Do I have to buy the vehicle from him?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to obtain a duplicate title from the DMV and then transfer the car with his signature once a replacement title is obtained, assuming the car is owned free and clear. If it is not, the car loan lender may need to be involved in the transaction.